# Zend Framework - Zend_File_Transfer Upload Handler

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-file

When using something like this in Zend:

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$upload->setDestination('/some/directory');
$upload->addValidator(x)
->addValidator(y);
$upload->receive();
```

Is the uploaded file uploaded first to a tmp directory, validated and then moved to 'some/directory' or is it directly saved into the setDestination directory?  If the former, it seems to me that this does the same as "move_uploaded_file" after it's been uploaded to a tmp dir.

Does ZF offer some type of http stream handler to write file to a specific directory natively?  i.e something similar to nodejs or django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http` use `move_uploaded_file` after verifying by validators that you assigned.

Look [here](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php):

```
public function receive($files = null)
{
    if (!$this->isValid($files)) {
        return false;
    }
    ... some code ...

    if (!move_uploaded_file($content['tmp_name'], $filename)) {
        if ($content['options']['ignoreNoFile']) {
            $this->_files[$file]['received'] = true;
            $this->_files[$file]['filtered'] = true;
            continue;
        }

        $this->_files[$file]['received'] = false;
        return false;
    }
```

There are no special mechanisms, it is just a wrapper over the standard function

For direct uploading to your directory you may use something like

```
$input = fopen("php://input", "r");
$file = fopen("/my/directory/filename.eee", "w");
while ($data = fread($input, 1024)){
    fwrite($file, $data);
}
```

but it seems in ZF is nothing like this

Comment: I figured there might be some wrapper for this as well but I guess regular good ol' PHP for now.